# Health insurance for senior Thai residents

Tags: health-insurance, thailand, health-care

I am searching for a basic health insurance to cover hospital costs in case of sickness for a **senior** Thai citizen.
I have found Bupa's offers of unlimited cover really appealing but unfortunately they seem to limit person's age to 66 years:

http://www.bupa.co.th/en/individuals/health-insurance/individual/index.asp

Any suggestions where to look for a senior person over 70?

Answer (score 5):

Thai citizens get health care effectively free (or very low cost) at government hospitals. I believe that there is not an upper age limit for this.

AIA claim to provide health care for people up to 80 years old : http://www.aia.co.th/en/individuals/products-and-services/life-insurance/medical-coverage/medical_coverage.html